# Error while publishing asp.net website on plesk

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hey am using vs 2017 to publish my asp.net mvc application but every time i get the error Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/csc.exe' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550). how do i fix this?

Comment: Open vs in administrator mode and try

Answer (score 0):

Go to the website destination, find the file in/roslyn/csc.exe, and do one of the following:
1.  Right click on it, make sure it is not read only, and set permissions to be full control by authorised users, or 
2.  Delete it

Then try publishing again.

Comment: 2>Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/csc.exe' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
2>Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/csi.exe' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).

Comment: same thing happens